# how do I detect a "long Tap" gesture on a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

In my app I'm displaying a table with different elements if a user taps on a tableviewcell a detailview gets pushed onto the navigationstack.
I now want to provide the user with abilty to "long tap" on a tableviewcell in order to pop up an alertview showing the user different options that can be applied on said tableviewcell (email information to a friend, print it out, add to bookmarks etc)

how do i implement a "long tap" gesture recognizer on a UITableViewCell??

thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at UILongPressGestureRecognizer?
See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer

You might want to consider a swipe gesture as seen in the Twitter app instead, though: I don't think that a long tap on a table cell would be very intuitive to use or expected by the user. Just my 2 cents.

- Johannes

Comment: This is a good one. but not suitable for uitableviewcells. Is is possible to display(nslog) the tableindex on longpressevent? I unable to work this gesture with uitableviewcells.

Answer (score 3):

on a touch down you would use a timer to fire off a method call in X number of seconds (how ever long you want the long touch to be). Then if they let go before that time you cancel the timer:

```
-(void) startSingleTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
 tapTouch = touch;
 tapTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:tapDelay target:self selector:@selector(singleTapGestureSucceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
}

-(void) cancelSingleTouch
{
 if(tapTimer)
 {
  [tapTimer invalidate];
  [tapTimer release];
 }

 tapTouch = nil;
 tapTimer = nil;
}
```